$d_1,d_2 $ are equivalent metrics $\iff$ they have the same convergent sequences
I read that: If $d_1,d_2 $ are metrics on $X \neq \emptyset $ then
$d_1,d_2 $ are equivalent metrics $\iff$ they have the same convergent sequences.
I have proved $(\Rightarrow). $
Also I can prove $(\Leftarrow) $ If we suppose that the convergent sequences have the same limit in both.
Namely if for $(x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\subset X$ and $x \in X $ holds: $d_1(x_k,x) \rightarrow 0 \iff d_2(x_k,x) \rightarrow 0$.
For that I used that:

A subset of a metric space is open if and only if its complement is closed.
A subset $A$ of a metric space is closed if and only if for every convergent sequence $a_n \to x$ in $X$ with $a_n \in A$ for all $n$ we also have $x \in A$.

Like that:
Suppose $F$ is $d_1$-closed. We show that $F$ is $d_2$-closed as well.
choose $x \in \overline{F}^{d_2}$. Then there is a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $F$ such that $x_n \to x(d_1) (n \to \infty) \Rightarrow x_n \to x(d_2) (n \to \infty)$ (Since these metric are equivalent)$\Rightarrow x \in \overline{F}^{d_1}= F$ since $F$ is $d_1$-closed.
Then $F= \overline{F}^{d_2}$, so $F$ is $d_2$-closed.
Similarly, I have proved that every $d_2$-closed set is also $d_1$-closed. So these metrics are equivalent.
But I suppose here that the sequence have the same limit. But in the question there is no condition like that the limit will be the same in these both metric spaces. We just know that a convergent sequence in one of them it will be convergent in the other one.(Maybe it will convergences to a different point in the other metric space.)
But I can't prove that if the convergent sequences are the same in both metrics (Limits maybe different)  then these metrics must be equivalent.

This question is similar to: Equivalent metrics $\iff$ same convergent sequences. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ash I have looked to this question. It helps me to prove the teorem if the limit point is the same for these two metrics. But I can't prove that if the sequence have two different points.

@ash I edited it. I hope it is more clear now.

Which definition of metric equivalence are you using?

@AdamRubinson I know two definition a one that with an inequality like that: $ \exists m,M>0 : \forall x,y \in X, md_1(x,y) \le d_2(x,y) \le Md_1(x,y) $ and the other that says equivalent metrics generate the same topology.

FWIW, I would use "(bi-)Lipschitz equiavalent" or "uniformly equivalent" for the first, and "equivalent" or "topologically equivalent" for the second

Those two definitions of "equivalent metrics" in your comment are not equivalent to each other, so they are not both equivalent to "they have the same convergent sequences".

So you really should clarify what you mean by equivalence of metrics, for purposes of this post.

@LeeMosher yes, I have totally forgotten that. Now, I can see that this theroem is true for Lipschitz equiavalent because I have used  Lipschitz equiavalent for this proof. Actually, Now I am wondering if this theorem is true when the equivalent metrics means topologically equivalent. Any idea?

It is always the case that if convergent sequences are the same then the limit are the same:
Consider a space $X$, and $d_1$, $d_2$ two distances on $X$. Suppose that the converging sequences wrt $d_1$ are the same as wrt to $d_2$.
Let $(x_n)_{n\geq0}$ be a sequence that is convergent wrt to $d_1$ to a certain limit $l$.
Define the sequence $(y_n)_{n\geq0}$ as follows: for all positive integers $n$, $y_{2n}=x_n$ and $y_{2n+1}=l$.
The sequence $(y_n)_{n\geq0}$ converges to $l$ wrt to $d_1$. As such, by hypothesis, it is a converging sequence wrt $d_2$. As $l$ is an accumulation point of $(y_n)_{n\geq0}$, we deduce that the limit of $(y_n)_{n\geq0}$ wrt to $d_2$ must be $l$. Then, every subsequence of $(y_n)_{n\geq0}$ is converging and converges to $l$. Thus, $(x_n)_{n\geq0}$ converges to $l$.
Edit: Based on the proof, we see that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq0}$ with $x_{2n}=1/n$ and $x_{2n+1}=a$ is convergent for $d_1$ but not for $d_2$ in the example from my previous answer bellow.
Consider the space $X=]0,1[\cup \{a,b\}$ where $a$ and $b$ are two distinct elements.
Define $d_1$ as follows : $\forall x,y\in]a,b[:~d_1(a,b)=1,~d_1(x,y)=|{x-y}|$, $d_1(x,a)=|{x}|$ and $d_1(x,b)=|{1-x}|$.
Now, define $d_2$ as such:  $\forall x,y\in]a,b[:~d_2(a,b)=1,~d_2(x,y)=|{x-y}|$, $d_2(x,a)=|{1-x}|$ and $d_2(x,b)=|{x}|$.

Thanks. I added my proof to my question. Can you help me for proving that these metrics are equivalent without saying that the limit is the same in both of them?

Sorry what I said is false, I will modify my answer so that it shows how it works.

Thank you very much
